# Electric looking thing found in ground

Tags: circuit-breaker

We are cleaning up our back yard from the previous owners. Found this today and I don’t know what it is. Is it our ground for the electric box? Kinda close to that. The previous owners also have a circuit breaker in the shed, also close to that. I feel Ike I should put dirt on it, but I want to know what it is first.

Picture of the thing and it’s relation to the electric box and the shed attached.

[[image][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i2OQG.jpg)

[image]

[image]

I carefully dug around it, trying not to touch the red part because I was worried it might be a live wire. I found a second smaller wire and followed that to another round thing. Noticed that the red wire went back around to the other round thing. It was pointed in the direction of the well so I was thinking it might be a pressure sensor for the well. Pulled up a clump of grass near it and the whole thing came out. It’s a bow
[image][image]

Comment: it looks like something that someone dropped on the ground ... have you tried to pick it up?

Comment: Yeah it feels like it is virtues and the wire is buried under the ground at a curtain point. I googled the model number on top and found this but I don’t know what it is. https://shop.daviscontrols.com/products/607-21B?locale=en If you scroll down to related products it has a metal thing with a black circle on top like this thing.

Comment: if you really want to identify the item, then clean the ground around it and then take the picture ... maybe dig away some of the dirt to expose it more

Comment: I carefully dug around it, trying not to touch the red part because I was worried it might be a live wire. I found a second smaller wire and followed that to another round thing. Noticed that the red wire went back around to the other round thing. It was pointed in the direction of the well so I was thinking it might be a pressure sensor for the well. Pulled up a clump of grass near it and the whole thing came out. It’s a bow.

Comment: a compound bow specifically ... looks like a toy

Comment: Yes, look around for some arrows, and possibly some Union soldiers...

Comment: Kinda funny but Indians used long bows + I think the relief is only ~15 lb on the Kayne’s little one but that gives 30 lbs or a little less great for teaching we usually have a few bales of straw out back where the kids shoot with there dad. Jstola those small bows would be in the same class as a 22 long rifle to a gun person both are quite small and can be lethal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a child’s compound bow at first I thought you were using it to point at something but it is quite clear that is what it is. We have a couple for the kids as one of my sons is a bow hunter he likes the challenge.